# Run dynamic code in current scope

Tags: c#, .net, eval

Is there any way to run dynamic codes can access variables in current scope like javascript eval or even if any script language can do this?

I'd like Jscript.net, but can't run in mono.

In my template system

```
<tag:field name="description" 
    eval="@this.Substring(0,@this.Length<100?@this.Length:100)" />
```

when execute this tag ,it will run this c# code and replace the tag

```
return Field["descripton"]
    .Substring(0,Field["descripton"].Length<100?Field["descripton"].Length:100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wont be able to provide an exact answer here, I think questing is bit open ended, so there may be other options.

But I've done something similar to this using the Flee (https://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LanguageReference) Library.

It allows you to execute arbitrary statements inside a context. You will have to create a closure context with all the variables the statement might need, and execute the statement.

Just a hint, but I know it worked for me.